# select matched and unmatched row from two datatable

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

I have two datatables as `dtAllTicket(ticket_id, name)` and `dtSpecialTicket(ticket_id)`

First of all, I want to retrieve all rows from `dtAllTicket`, where `ticket_id` not present in `dtSpecialTicket`

Then, I want to retrieve all rows from `dtSpecialTicket`, where `ticket_id` is present in both tables

Comment: INNER and LEFT JOIN are your friends

Comment: have tried following for first query

Comment: DataTable dtUnmatched = (from a in _sourceDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                              join b in _dtTicket.AsEnumerable()
                                              on a["ticket_id"].ToString() equals b["ticket_id"].ToString()
                                              into g
                                              where g.Count() == 0
                                              select a).CopyToDataTable();

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq-To-DataSet` and `Enumerable.Join`, for example:

```
var specialInBoth = from rowSpecial in dtSpecialTicket.AsEnumerable()
                    join rowAll in dtAllTicket.AsEnumerable()
                    on rowSpecial.Field<int>("ticket_id") equals rowAll.Field<int>("ticket_id") 
                    select rowSpecial;

var specialIDs = new HashSet<int>(dtSpecialTicket.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<int>("ticket_id")));
var allNotInSpecial = from rowAll in dtAllTicket.AsEnumerable()
                      let id = rowAll.Field<int>("ticket_id") 
                      where !specialIDs.Contains(id)
                      select rowAll;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dtUpdate = new HashSet<int>(_dtTicket.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(row => row.Field<int>("ticket_id")));

var varUnmatched = from all in _sourceDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                   let id = all.Field<int>("ticket_id")
                   where !dtUpdate.Contains(id)
                   select all;
DataTable dtInsert = varUnmatched.CopyToDataTable();

var varMatched = from all in _sourceDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                 let id = all.Field<int>("ticket_id")
                 where dtUpdate.Contains(id)
                 select all;
DataTable dtDelete = varMatched.CopyToDataTable();
```